# How to get required links from google search into python?

Tags: python

I am using python 3.3.3 doing my project and trying to get all those links which are required for example if I have written C++ in search (as for url), then its all links should get by python and save into txt files. Here is the illustration:
 Google Search : C++

Output result in txt file:

```
www.cplusplus.com
www.tutorialspoint.com/c++
```

and so on

( Right now I have successfully extracted the data from web for calculating the text complexity and finding the clustering and so on that is what I have to do. )

this code is extracting data from web:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve( "https://www.python.org", "C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\python\\s\\newfile.txt" )
```

but I want also to happen like as I have said upper.

I searched a lot, not getting specific even good tutorial about this approach.

Is there any way to extract those required links?

Comment: your question is not clear, you want google search on specif word and store the link in file, or you wan to search link in particular website??

Comment: i am doing programming on python and i am trying to get that link which i have search for e.g i search on google for c++ and google showed me some reuslts. Now i want to get all those results which google has done for me, in the txt file using pyhton

Answer (score 0):

you can use google api to do it.
first you have to register and enable your custom search in google to get key and cx https://www.google.com/cse/all

the api format is:

'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=yourkey&cx=yourcx&alt=json&q=yourquery'

customsearch is the google function you want to use, in your case I think it is customsearch 
v1 is the version of you app
yourkey and yourcx are provided from google you could find it on you dashboard
yourquery is the term you want to search, in your case is "Medicine:pdf"
json is the return format
the userInput is the query you want to search.

```
def googleAPICall(userInput):
        result = []
        try:  
            userInput = urllib.quote(userInput)        
            for i in range(0,1):
                index = i*10+1 
                url = ('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?'    
                       'key=%s'
                       '&cx=%s'
                       '&alt=json'
                       '&num=10'
                       '&start=%d'
                       '&q=%s')%(self.KEY,self.CX,index,userInput)   
                print (url)

                request = urllib2.Request(url)
                response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            returnResults = simplejson.load(response)
            webs = returnResults['items'] 

            for web in webs:
                result.append(web["link"])
        except:
            print ("search error")
            result.append("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B")

        return result
```

Comment: can u tell me how is getting input on console?

Comment: 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=yourkey&cx=yourcx&alt=json&q=yourquery' giving me {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyInvalid",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}

Comment: i visited and tried to do but failed wt u have said

Comment: yourkey ,yourcx and yourquery must be replaced by your own numbers which could be found after you register.

Comment: on left there is "Edit search engine option",help, and "sendfeed back" option so which shell i use?

Comment: key can be found at  apis & auth -> credentials https://code.google.com/apis/console

Comment: cx can be found at  edit search engine -> setup -> search engine ID  https://www.google.com/cse/all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64060/discussion-between-user3440716-and-galaxyan).